# HTML Bootstrap - Display two buttons 50% of the Div's width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window that needs to display two buttons at the bottom, say **Proceed** and **Cancel** using Bootstrap's button for this.

I want these buttons to be side by side occupying the whole width of the div.

If I set the width of the buttons to be `50%`, they are shown one on top of the other. Only when I set the width, say, 49% they are shown next to each other, but then they are not taking the whole width.

I've seen this many times, but can't figure out how to do it.

Here is a sample code of what I'm doing:

```
<div align="center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Cancel()"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Cancel</font></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="Proceed()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Proceed</font></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, inspired by the received comments, I got a working solution (can't judge its elegance, but the result is what I was looking for):

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=" btn-warning" ng-click="Cancel()"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 10px 0;cursor:pointer">
                <font size="6">Cancel</font>
            </td>
            <td class=" btn-success" ng-click="Proceed()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 10px 0;cursor:pointer">
                <font size="6">Proceed</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is shown as two rectangles occupying the whole width, and correctly shrinking with the screen.

Comment: This is not tabular data in any way, shape, or form.  You're best off using flexbox for something like this, but even `display: table-cell` would be better than this solution.

Comment: @hackle, _...not tabular data..._. Well, long ago I found that some sites (like Facebook just to mention one) use tables for presenting **Username/Password** prompts and the corresponding input elements. So, If they do that, I feel comfortable doing it too.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `class` on the first `button` and give it `float:left`.It will be take whole `width`.See the working demo in [Bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/xauzae0UBD)

```css
.hell {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div align="center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning hell" ng-click="Cancel()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Cancel</font>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="Proceed()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Proceed</font>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @ChoncholMahmud. You solution looks quite similar to the one I worked out (see above the answer starting with "**Well, inspired by the received comments...**".

Answer (score 4):

"btn-block" is what you'd generally want so the buttons stretch within their columns (for anyone finding this in Google).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Proceed</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: **btn-block** was removed from Bootstrap 5.0, try **w-100** instead if you've upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

Do this .

```
<div align="center">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Cancel()"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Cancel</font></button>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="Proceed()" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:50%"><font size="6">Proceed</font></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

By the way, you shouldn't be using align="center", that's old school HTML, bootstrap already has a class for this, instead of doing this

```
<div align="center">
```

do this

```
<div class="text-center">
```

the col-md-6 class on those divs are the ones that establish the 50% , if you want less you can use other classes like col-md-1 all they up to col-md-12

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you try that? I did and it does not work. I set the width of the buttons to 100% and the margin of the internal divs to 0, and there is a gap between the two buttons. Only when setting padding=0 to the internal divs it looks it is ok, though I get the buttons moving one on top of the other when I shrink the window.

Comment: that gap is the padding of the columns, 15px padding on both sides, this is how bootstrap was done,  if you don't the buttons to stack on mobile just add the class col-xs-6 to the div with columns col-md-6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `inline blocks` then you will encounter this issue.

Try using a `margin right` fix to prevent the wrapping:

HTML

```
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="block block-1">Block 1</div>
    <div class="block block-2">Block 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.block-1 {
    margin-right: -0.2em; /* spacing fix */ 
}
```

Here is a Codepen with a fix for your scenario: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZmKYr

Comment: Please take a look at the sample code I added to my question. I'm dealing with Bootstrap buttons, not blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has the `clearfix` class, which can be able to use `float-left` and `float-right` classes.

Here is how to use: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/

An example:

```
<div class="clearfix">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-left" style="width: 48%;">Save</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" style="width: 48%;">Cancel</button>
</div>
```